# what is the location on disk when deployed package files stores in Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, location, package

When we deploy any app in to azure, in Which location, these uploaded files stored  disk?. and in which format the files stored?

Comment: Can your clarify what kind of apps you want to deploy? It's different between Web App  and APP which runs in Azure VM.

Comment: Aside from web app and vm that @WayneYang-MSFT mentioned, there are also cloud services, which have distinct package definitions.